# What's the difference/compatibility between aiohttp and websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

What's the difference between `aiohttp`'s websocket support (i.e. `WebSocketResponse`) and [websockets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets)   (both offer an async support)? Can they be mixed?

Comment: you could probably mix them but is there any reason you don't just want to use aiohttp's built-in websockets?

Comment: the two are on top of Python’s asynchronous I/O support introduced in PEP 3156, so I think the performance is really similar

Comment: autobhan also seems to be an alternative.

Comment: @Rhangaun I recommend not wasting your time with autobahn. If your task is simple, just use `websockets`. Autobahn is a lot harder to debug and much more complex and likely be an overkill in most cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are two different libraries maintained by different people. Both are built on top of [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

[`websockets`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) aims to be a simple easy to use library to implement websockets clients and servers and is maintained mostly by a [single developer](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/graphs/contributors). On the other hand, [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) is a quite bigger library maintained by [bigger team](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/graphs/contributors), offering not only websockets but, as the name suggests, HTTP functionality as well. Some of its functionality overlaps that of [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), but in a async fashion.

In terms of size, `websockets` is about 4k LOC, while `aiohttp` is about 40k LOC. If you just need a simple and easy to use websockets client, go for `websockets`. If you are already using `aiohttp` and need websockets functionality, use what `aiohttp` has to offer. I don't see a point in mixing them.

Answer (score 0):

Noting a detail that may force the choice for folks that need to support the system Python in Debian 8: `aiohttp` sets its [minimum supported version](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-is-python-3-5-3-the-lowest-supported-version) at Python 3.5.3 (which is the system Python version in Debian 9).

While the `aiohttp` folks have good reasons for making that decision, the smaller feature set in `websockets` allows that project to maintain support for the Python 3.4.x system Python in Debian 8, albeit with some adaptation of your own application code to be Python 3.4 compatible: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#python-lt-36